# How to rotate a material on a plane

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

Does anyone know how to rotate the texture pattern to be horizontal on my plane and not vertical (pictured)? I'm relatively new to blender and have tried everything I can think of - please note I am using 2.8. 
I've tried to UV unwrap but nothing happens, and messing with the rotation options in my mapping nodes only adjusts the "spots", but not their actual rotation. I'm pulling my hair out over here - help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on the UV map orientation... you should add a picture of it.

Comment: But you can simply rotate 90° around the Z axis of the mapping nodes and set them to "texture"

Comment: "the spots"? What does that mean? What spots? What does your texture look like? If you want the mapping to be the same for both textures, use just one mapping node, not two like you are doing, you have to make the same changes twice.

Comment: That's a problem I'm having - I'm currently selecting the plane> U> Smart UV Project> and hitting okay on the default options. If I press "unwrap" it says "object has no uniform scale, unwrap will operate on a non-scaled version of the mesh." So I don't think my UV is correct either..  Should I be setting my texture coordinate to something else and not UV?

Comment: Also setting 90 on which Z axis? The Rotation, Location, or Scale? Either way, none of those work for me. :/ and as far as I know, I already have my mapping set to "texture", right?

Comment: Applying the scale (Ctrl + A) could help. I think.

Comment: Nope, nothing :( @LeoNas

Comment: I figured it out... I just kept messing with the settings and I still don't really know how I did it. Texture Map Connected to a Generated Coordinate. Locations: 0, Rotation: X-19.3, Scale: X-5.990, Y-35.800, Z-0.200... It doesn't make sense to me by any account, but at least I have something for now.

Comment: @Katie, 90° for Z rotation.

Comment: UV maps are X and Y only. So rotating around Z will change the orientation of X and Y. (may be more complicated if you wanted to use 'generated' or 'object' slots from the texture coordinates but this is not the case here).

Comment: If still not working, you should upload your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that we could concretely give you the good setup.

Comment: @lemon, I figured it out! Thanks for the help. I will keep the site in mind when I inevitably have issues again.